# Web forms : sending image into email not displaying in outlook?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm sending an image through web form the image is displayed well into gmail ,yahoo etc.
But i'm not able to view that image when I send it on Outlook 
what would be wrong please help.

Code:

```
//Variable mg have a html code with  'cid:uniqueId1’ calls image from function SendMail12


void birthday()
        {
            Coonection con = new Coonection();
            sql = "select es.PORTNO,es.SERVERNAME,es.EMAILID,es.PASSWORD,e.efrom,e.SerNo,e.eto,e.ecc,e.emessage,e.eflag,e.EmpID,e.FIRSTNAME,e.LASTNAME,e.DeptName,e.FromDate,e.Todate,e.Reason from EMAILSETTING es,EmailSender e";


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con.GetConnection());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            string sub = "Message";
            int portnum, n,sn;
            string servername1, passwo, account, t, ecc, mg, flage,mg2;
            sql = "select count(srno)from EmailSender";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con.GetConnection());
            // dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            n = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            //while (i)
            //{
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    portnum = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PORTNO"].ToString());
                    servername1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SERVERNAME"].ToString();      //Table(0).Rows(0)("SmtpServerName").ToString();
                    account = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMAILID"].ToString();
                    passwo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PASSWORD"].ToString();
                    t = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["eto"].ToString();
                    ecc = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ecc"].ToString();
                    mg2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["emessage"].ToString();
                    flage = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["eflag"].ToString();
                    sn = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SerNo"].ToString());

                    if (flage == "N" && mg2 == "Wish You a Very Happy Returns of the Day.<P> From - Daccess Security Systems Pvt ")
                    {
                        mg = " <html> " +
                            "<body background= 'meet.jpg'>" +
                           "<head>  " +
                           "<title>Untitled Document</title>  " +
                           "<meta content='text/plain; charset=us-ascii' http-equiv='Content-Type' />" +
                           "<style type='text/css'>  " +
                           ".style1 {  " +
                               "font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  " +
                               "font-weight: bold;  " +
                               "font-size: 18px;  " +
                               "color: #3333CC;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           ".style3 {  " +
                               "font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;  " +
                               "color: #003399;  " +
                           "}    " +
                           ".style4 {  " +
                               "font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  " +
                               "font-weight: bold;  " +
                               "font-size: 12px;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           ".style11 {  " +
                               "color: #1A588D;  " +
                               "font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;  " +
                               "font-weight: bold;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           ".style15 {  " +
                               "color: #1A588D;  " +
                               "font-weight: bold;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           ".style18 {color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; }  " +
                           "body {  " +
                               "margin-top: 1px;  " +
                               "margin-left: 1px;  " +
                               "margin-right: 1px;  " +
                               "margin-bottom: 1px;  " +

                           "}  " +
                           "</style>  " +
                           "<link href='Untitled-1.htm' id='1' title='view'>  " +
                           "<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>  " +
                           "function MM_reloadPage(init) {   " +
                             "if (init==true) with (navigator) {if ((appName=='Netscape')&&(parseInt(appVersion)==4)) {  " +
                               "document.MM_pgW=innerWidth; document.MM_pgH=innerHeight; onresize=MM_reloadPage; }}  " +
                             "else if (innerWidth!=document.MM_pgW || innerHeight!=document.MM_pgH) location.reload();  " +
                           "}  " +
                           "MM_reloadPage(true);  " +
                           "</script>  " +
                           "<style type='text/css'>  " +
                           "a:link {  " +
                               "text-decoration: none;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           "a:visited {  " +
                               "text-decoration: none;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           "a:hover {  " +
                               "text-decoration: none;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           "a:active {  " +
                               "text-decoration: none;  " +
                           "}  " +
                           ".style20 {font-size: 12px}  " +
                           "</style></head>  " +
                           "<body>  " +
                           "<p class='style1'><img src='cid:uniqueId' width='145' height='111'></p>  " +
                           "<table border= 1 align ='left'>" +
                           "<tr>" + "<td>Employee ID :" + "</td>" +
                           "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EmpID"].ToString() + "</td>" +
                           "</tr>" +
                           "<tr>" + "<td>Employee Name :" + "</td>" +
                           "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FIRSTNAME"].ToString() + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LASTNAME"].ToString() + "</td>" +
                           "</tr>" +
                           "<tr>" + "<td>Department :" + "</td>" +
                           "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DeptName"].ToString() + "</td>" +
                           "</tr>" +
                           "<tr>" + "<td>Message :" + "</td>" +
                           "<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["emessage"].ToString() + "</td>" +
                           "</tr>" +
                           "<tr>"+
                           "<td>"+
                           "<pre align='left' class='style3'><strong><img src='cid:uniqueId1' width='286' height='177'></strong></pre>  " +
                           "<pre align='left' class='style4'> <a name='t'></a> Please do not reply to this email.</pre>" +
                           "<p align='left' class='style3'>&nbsp;</p>  " +
                           "</td>"+"</tr>"+"</table>"+
                           "</body>  " +
                           "</html>  ";

                        if (flage == "N" && mg2 == "Wish You a Very Happy Returns of the Day.<P> From - Daccess Security Systems Pvt ")
                        {
                            SendMail12(account, passwo, t, sub, mg, ecc, servername1, portnum);
                            sql = "Update EmailSender set eflag ='Y' where SerNo = '" + sn.ToString() + "'";
                            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(sql, con.GetConnection());
                            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    servername1 = "";
                    portnum = 0;
                    account = "";
                    passwo = "";
                    MessageBox.Show("Email Setting Is Not Stored");
                }
            }
        }

// Send mail function
public static bool SendMail12(string gMailAccount, string password, string to, string subject, string message, string cc, string server, int port)
      {
          try
          {


              NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(gMailAccount, password);
              MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
              msg.From = new MailAddress(gMailAccount);
              msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

              string[] s;
              s = cc.Split(';');

              for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
              {
                  msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(s[i].ToString()));
              }

              msg.Subject = subject;
              msg.Body = message;
              msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

              SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
              client.Host = server;
              client.Port = port;
              client.Timeout = 100000;
              client.EnableSsl = true;
              client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
              client.Credentials = loginInfo;
              string palinBody = "Plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html";
              AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(palinBody, null, "text/plain");
              string htmlBody = message;
              AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, "text/html");
              //create the AlternateView for embedded image 
              AlternateView imageView = new AlternateView("D:\\Aniket Work\\New Folder Update\\EmailSender\\EmailSender\\images\\Daccess-logo.gif", MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);
              imageView.ContentId = "uniqueId";
              imageView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

              AlternateView imageView1 = new AlternateView("D:\\Aniket Work\\New Folder Update\\EmailSender\\EmailSender\\images\\birthday1images.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
              imageView1.ContentId = "uniqueId1";
              imageView1.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
              //add the views 
              msg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
              msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
              msg.AlternateViews.Add(imageView);
              msg.AlternateViews.Add(imageView1);

              client.Send(msg);

              return true;
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
```

[image]

Comment: That's a real example of spaghetti code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be giving absolute paths to your resources

e.g.

in above code, your body background should be something like

```
<body background= 'http://yourdomain.com/meet.jpg'>
```

same thing applies to your image tag or you can have inline content disposition

**EDIT**

Do you see something like this when you view the mail?

[image]

Comment: thanks but working fine for gmail,yahoo mail image is only not able to display into outlook why?

Comment: is there any warning message displayed when you view the email?

Comment: NO SUCH ERROR EVEN WHEN I RIGHT CLICK ON IMAGE I DONT HAVE DOWNLOAD OPTION ONLY COPY OPTION IS THERE ...strange ...

Comment: this info text is displayed on top your reading pane. what is your outlook version?

Comment: yes I know that error message :( but not getting it ... i'm using outlook 2007